# jquery selector: how to focus on the next input in a table cell?

Tags: jquery, css

I got a form where all textbox and select inputs are in different `<td>` in one `<tr>`.

The selection of the first `<select>` will decide which textboxes will be visible in the following `<td>`s. So I am to reload the whole `<tr>` ajaxly and then focus on the next `<input>`.

My current JavaScript:

```
var $nextAll = $('#ExpenseTypeId').closest('td').nextAll('td');
```

And then check if the `<td>` has an `<input>` inside. In a `for` loop, I detect which one is my next `<input>`, which will have focus.

But, is there an easy way to do that? I hope to have something like:

```
$('#ExpenseTypeId').closest('td').nextAll('td input').first().focus();
```

Obviously the `nextAll('id input')` does not work as supposed. How to write a correct selector?

Comment: `$('#ExpenseTypeId').closest('td').nextAll('td').find("input:first").focus();`

Comment: Thanks, Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is provided by

```
$('#ExpenseTypeId').closest('td').nextAll('td').find("input:first").focus();
```

Another solution I find out now is to add `:has()` selector:

```
$('#ExpenseTypeId').closest('td').nextAll('td:has(input)').first().find('input').focus();
```